# SASS: @media query not working

Tags: css, sass

in my SASS file the media query is not working properly. It does change the background color but fails to change the text. Appreciate your time and help. Here is the HTML and SASS code:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="mobile_only">Mobile only</div>
<div class="tablet_only">Tablet only</div>
<div class="desktop_only">Desktop only</div>
<div class="mobile_and_tablet">Mobile and Tablet</div>
<div class="tablet_and_desktop">Tablet and Desktop</div>
<div class="all_views">All views</div>

<!-- SASS -->
@mixin mq($display, $breakpoint)
    @media #{$display} and #{$breakpoint}
        @content

$mq_phone: "(max-width: 400px)"
$mq_tablet: "(min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 700px)"
$mq_phone_tablet: "(max-width: 700px)"
$mq_laptop: "(min-width: 701px)"
$mq_tablet_laptop: "(min-width: 401px)"

+mq("screen",$mq_phone)
    body
        background: red
    .mobile_only
        display: block
+mq("screen",$mq_phone_tablet)
    .mobile_and_tablet
        display: block
+mq("screen",$mq_tablet)
    body
        background: blue
    .tablet_only
        display: block
+mq("screen",$mq_tablet_laptop)
    .tablet_and_desktop
        display: block
+mq("screen",$mq_laptop)
    body
        background: green
    .desktop_only
        display: block
```

Comment: I can't see any styles in that code that would change the text colour?

Comment: Sorry i wasnt precise with the question. I didnt mean the color of the text but the actual text itself. When i resize the window to 400px it still shows t"Desktop only" element in it when it shouldnt.

Answer (score 0):

You have to need add color property....

```css
@mixin mq($display, $breakpoint)
    @media #{$display} and #{$breakpoint}
        @content

$mq_phone: "(max-width: 400px)"
$mq_tablet: "(min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 700px)"
$mq_phone_tablet: "(max-width: 700px)"
$mq_laptop: "(min-width: 701px)"
$mq_tablet_laptop: "(min-width: 401px)"

+mq("screen",$mq_phone)
    body
        background: red
        color:  white
    .mobile_only
        display: block
+mq("screen",$mq_phone_tablet)
    .mobile_and_tablet
        display: block
+mq("screen",$mq_tablet)
    body
        background: blue
        color:  white
    .tablet_only
        display: block
+mq("screen",$mq_tablet_laptop)
    .tablet_and_desktop
        display: block
+mq("screen",$mq_laptop)
    body
        background: green
        color:    white
    .desktop_only
        display: block
```

```html
<div class="mobile_only">Mobile only</div>
<div class="tablet_only">Tablet only</div>
<div class="desktop_only">Desktop only</div>
<div class="mobile_and_tablet">Mobile and Tablet</div>
<div class="tablet_and_desktop">Tablet and Desktop</div>
<div class="all_views">All views</div>
```

Comment: Hi momin thanks for your reply. Sorry my question wasnt precise enough.  I wasnt asking about the color of the text but the text itself. So element with desktop_only class is still showing on the screen even when i resize it to 400px.